# Morphisms between K3 surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, positive-characteristic, k3-surfaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be K3 surfaces over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Is it possible to have a dominant morphism $X\to Y$ which is not an isomorphism?

In positive characteristic, the Frobenius and its iterates give examples of dominant morphisms between K3 surfaces which are not isomorphisms. Are there any others?

Comment: there are many examples (in any characteristic) of dominant *rational* maps $X\dashrightarrow Y$ between K3 surfaces, and also many examples of nontrivial automorphisms of K3 surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:X\to Y$ was such a map, it is unramified since $K_X,K_Y$ are trivial. So,it is finite and thus an etale covering. But these are simply connected and thus it must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer. To add a few words, I believe that your argument shows that any such map is an isomorphism if $f$ is generically \'{e}tale, and in particular this answers the question in characteristic 0.